# How to draw image through file path

Tags: java, graphics

I am attempting to have an image show up through file path. I have the image in my src folder, and I've tried maybe 5 different types of code.

Ignore the commented out code, those are just shapes i was drawing to test

I've tried it with both file path and file name and nothing has worked. Its not giving me any errors or anything either.

```
public void ImagePanel() {
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File("BMan.jpg"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JPanel panel = new MyPanel();
}
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){

    super.paintComponent(g);
    //g.setColor(Color.RED);
    //g.fillOval(CircleX, CircleY, CircleH, CircleW);
    //g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    //g.fillRect(SquareX, SquareY, SquareW, SquareH);
    g.drawImage(image, 50, 50, this);

}
```

Comment: try again with `ex.printStackTrace()` in your `catch`, instead. That might give you more information... Also, is there a JFrame this is in? Or is the JPanel the only thing there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my implementation of the component:

```
public class ImageView extends JComponent
        implements ComponentListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3761966077344495154L;

    private BufferedImage image;
    private int imageX;
    private int imageY;
    private int imageWidth;
    private int imageHeight;

    /** Creates a new instance of ImageView */
    public ImageView() {
        addComponentListener(this);
    }


    public BufferedImage getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public Rectangle getImageBounds() {
        if (image == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return new Rectangle(imageX, imageY, imageWidth, imageHeight);
        }
    }

    public void setImage(final BufferedImage newValue) {
        image = newValue;
        computeBounds();
        repaint();
    }


    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        long tm = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (isOpaque()) {
            g.setColor(getBackground());
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }

        BufferedImage img = image;
        if (img != null) {
            g.drawImage(img, imageX, imageY, imageWidth, imageHeight, null);
        }
        tm = System.currentTimeMillis()-tm;
    }

    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        computeBounds();
    }

    public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
    }

    public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
        computeBounds();
    }

    public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {
    }

    private void computeBounds() {
        BufferedImage img = image;
        if (img != null) {
            int width = this.getWidth();
            int height = this.getHeight();
            int wi = img.getWidth();
            int hi = img.getHeight();
            imageWidth = width;
            imageHeight = height;
            imageX = 0;
            imageY = 0;
            if (wi*height < hi*width) {
                imageWidth = wi*height/hi;
                imageX = (width-imageWidth)/2;
            } else {
                imageHeight = hi*width/wi;
                imageY = (height-imageHeight)/2;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `JFrame` where you will put the panel:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("title");
    frame.setSize(400,400);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //all the other things for the jframe
    JPanel panel = new MyPanel();
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.repaint();
}
```